# how to find out all non-constant entire functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Find all non-constant entire functions $f(z)$ with real integer Taylor coefficients at $z = 0$ such that $f(1/n)=-f(-1/n)$ and $|f(z)|\le 3|z|$ for all $z$ such that $|z|>10$.

. have no idea how to state this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it for all $n$? I would start by considering $f(z)+ f(-z)$.

Comment: yes, it is for all $n$.

Comment: It seems to me that $f$ is odd, hence $f(z)/z$ is entire and bounded, hence constant.